# Huawei In App Purchase sandbox testing , I cannot purchase the item I have already purchased once

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

In the IAP sandbox test, consumables and non-consumables cannot be purchased again after being purchased once. As a result, the payment page cannot be displayed. In onActivityResult, the IAP SDK returns code

```
ORDER_PRODUCT_OWNED 60051
```

Is this a general problem or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

60051 means A user failed to purchase a product because the user already owns the  product. and @Disavowed has given the explanation and solution.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/iap-ExceptionHandlingAndGeneralErrorCodes-v4

Here is the code on how to consume the product.

```
/**
 * Consume the unconsumed purchase with type 0 after successfully delivering the product, then the Huawei payment server will update the order status and the user can purchase the product again.
 * @param inAppPurchaseData JSON string that contains purchase order details.
 */
private void consumeOwnedPurchase(final Context context, String inAppPurchaseData) {
    Log.i(TAG, "call consumeOwnedPurchase");
    IapClient mClient = Iap.getIapClient(context);
    Task<ConsumeOwnedPurchaseResult> task = mClient.consumeOwnedPurchase(createConsumeOwnedPurchaseReq(inAppPurchaseData));
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ConsumeOwnedPurchaseResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ConsumeOwnedPurchaseResult result) {
            // Consume success
            Log.i(TAG, "consumeOwnedPurchase success");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Pay success, and the product has been delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (e instanceof IapApiException) {
                IapApiException apiException = (IapApiException)e;
                Status status = apiException.getStatus();
                int returnCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                Log.e(TAG, "consumeOwnedPurchase fail,returnCode: " + returnCode);
            } else {
                // Other external errors
            }

        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create a ConsumeOwnedPurchaseReq instance.
 * @param purchaseData JSON string that contains purchase order details.
 * @return ConsumeOwnedPurchaseReq
 */
private ConsumeOwnedPurchaseReq createConsumeOwnedPurchaseReq(String purchaseData) {

    ConsumeOwnedPurchaseReq req = new ConsumeOwnedPurchaseReq();
    // Parse purchaseToken from InAppPurchaseData in JSON format.
    try {
        InAppPurchaseData inAppPurchaseData = new InAppPurchaseData(purchaseData);
        req.setPurchaseToken(inAppPurchaseData.getPurchaseToken());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "createConsumeOwnedPurchaseReq JSONExeption");
    }

    return req;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Error Code **60051** means A user failed to purchase a product because the user already owns the product.

**Solution:** Use the obtainOwnedPurchases API to check whether the user has purchased the product.

For a consumable that has been purchased, call the consumeOwnedPurchase API to consume the product after it is delivered. After being consumed, the product can be purchased next time.
If the product is a non-consumable product or a subscription, the product cannot be purchased again.

Queries information about all purchased in-app products, including consumables, non-consumables, and auto-renewable subscriptions.

- If the information about consumables is returned, the consumables
  might not be delivered due to some exceptions. In this case, your app
  needs to check whether the consumables are delivered. If not, the app
  needs to deliver them and calls the consumeOwnedPurchase API to
  consume them.
- If the information about non-consumables is returned,
  the non-consumables do not need to be consumed.
- If the information
  about subscriptions is returned, all existing subscription
  relationships of the user in the app are returned.
- If purchaseState is **0** that means product is **PURCHASED**.
- If purchaseState is **1** that means product is **CANCELED**.
- If purchaseState is **2** that means product is **PURCHASED**.

**Code:**

```
public void checkUserOwnedTheProduct(final Context context) {
        OwnedPurchasesReq ownedPurchasesReq = new OwnedPurchasesReq();
        ownedPurchasesReq.setPriceType(productType);
        Task<OwnedPurchasesResult> task = Iap.getIapClient(context).obtainOwnedPurchases(ownedPurchasesReq);
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<OwnedPurchasesResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(OwnedPurchasesResult result) {
                // Obtain the execution result.
                if (result != null && result.getInAppPurchaseDataList() != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.getInAppPurchaseDataList().size(); i++) {
                        String inAppPurchaseData = result.getInAppPurchaseDataList().get(i);
                        String inAppSignature = result.getInAppSignature().get(i);
                        boolean success = CipherUtil.doCheck(inAppPurchaseData, inAppSignature, Key.getPublicKey());
                        if (success) {
                            try {
                                InAppPurchaseData inAppPurchaseDataBean = new InAppPurchaseData(inAppPurchaseData);
                                int purchaseState = inAppPurchaseDataBean.getPurchaseState();                            

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (productType == IapClient.PriceType.IN_APP_NONCONSUMABLE) {
                        ((HmsInAppPurchaseList) context).loadList();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof IapApiException) {
                    IapApiException apiException = (IapApiException) e;
                    Status status = apiException.getStatus();
                    int returnCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                } else {
                    // Other external errors
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

For More Information you can visit these links:
**In-App Purchase Article:**

**Client Side:** https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201255229704010231&fid=0101187876626530001

**Server Side:** https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201273064244120101&fid=0101187876626530001

**In-App Purchase Github Link:**

**Client Side:** https://github.com/DTSE-India-Community/HMS-In-App-Purchase-Kit

**Server Side:**
https://github.com/DTSE-India-Community/Huawei-In-App-Purchase-And-Push-Kit-Server_Side-Implementation

Answer (score 1):

In the sandbox environment, you can purchase consumables and non-consumables. After purchasing them, you can consume them. After that, you can purchase them again to facilitate tests.

Invoke the consumption interface to consume the offering.